# Crop and scale an image in SVG

Tags: css, svg

I have an SVG element in my HTML which includes two external files, another SVG and a Bitmap.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    width="1024" height="768">
        <image xlink:href="bitmap.png" />
        <image xlink:href="outline.svg" />
</svg>
```

My aim is that I can swap out the Bitmap for another (of any size) and have the Bitmap:

1. Scale down to a specific width (maintaining ratio aspect)
2. Crop off the bottom part of the bitmap

I've tried using clipPath, viewBox on sub SVG elements encapsulating the bitmap image, and I can't nail the problem. I'm trying to do this without JavaScript (if I can help it).

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the [`preserveAspectRatio`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#PreserveAspectRatioAttribute) attribute:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    width="200" height="45">

    <image id="img" x="0" y="0"
        width="100%" height="100%"
        xlink:href="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/logos/so/so-logo.png"
        preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin slice"/>
</svg>
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/b7bE6/)